# The returned result is null after price is updated with java vdm generated for custom odata service

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We have a custom OData service(function import) to update price in S/4HANA on-premise system(1909). And I used Java VDM Generator to generate VDM for this OData Service.

OData Service to update price

/sap/opu/odata/SAP/***/ChangePrice?SalesOrganisation='***'&Plant='***'&MaterialNumber='***'&ConditionAmount=2100&ConditionUnit='EUR'&ValidFrom=datetime'2019-01-01T00:00:00'&ValidTo=datetime'2019-12-31T00:00:00'

After I called the changePrice method and the price is updated in S/4HANA system but the returned entity (priceCondUpdated) is null.

```
        TransferPriceCondition priceCondUpdated = service.changePrice(condUnit, 
                                                   price,
                                                   materialNo,
                                                   plant,
                                                   LocalDateTime.of(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                                                   LocalDateTime.of(2019, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0),
                                                      salesOrg).execute(DestinationUtil.getHttpDestination());
```

I debugged the source code of SAP Cloud SDK and found that the OData Service gave a correct response.

OData response

{"__metadata":{"id":"http://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/***/TransferPriceCondition(SalesOrganisation='***',Plant='***',MaterialNumber='***')","uri":"http://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/***/TransferPriceCondition(SalesOrganisation='***',Plant='***',MaterialNumber='***')","type":"***.TransferPriceCondition"},"SalesOrganisation":"1709","Plant":"***","MaterialNumber":"***","ConditionAmount":"123.000","ConditionUnit":"EUR","ValidFrom":"/Date(1546346659000)/","ValidTo":"/Date(1577796259000)/"}

When it was going to get entity from response in SDK, see source code below responseJsonObject does not contain edmFunctionImportName(changePrice). So it would return null.

Source code of FunctionImportResponseParser.java in Cloud SDK

```
@Nullable
<T> T getEntityFromResponse(
    final InputStream responseContent,
    final String edmFunctionImportName,
    final Class<? extends T> entityJavaType )
    throws IOException,
        IllegalArgumentException
{
    final JsonObject responseJsonObject = getJsonObjectFromResponse(responseContent);

    if( responseJsonObject.has(edmFunctionImportName) ) {
        final JsonElement jsonElement = responseJsonObject.get(edmFunctionImportName);
        return getEntityFromJsonElement(jsonElement, entityJavaType);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Could you help to take a look at this issue?

SAP Cloud SDK Version: 3.3.1
S/4HANA On premise: 1909

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the well documented question! Please use the *SAP Cloud SDK* version 3.6.0 and above. We fixed the parsing of OData function import results.

Best regards,
Alexander

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it on Version 3.6 +.